# Formula (filter) to make array with subtotals in one category (like a pivot table)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with the following columns:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Person | Competence | Category | Sub-category |
| 2 | Name1 | 4 | A | XX |
| 3 | Name1 | 1 | A | YY |
| 4 | Name1 | 2 | A | ZZ |
| 5 | Name1 | 2 | B | ZZ |
| 6 | Name2 | 3 | A | ZZ |
| 7 | Name2 | 5 | A | YY |
| 8 | Name2 | 4 | B | ZZ |
| 9 | Name3 | 5 | B | ZZ |

Then if you would need an array with all competence values of all people in category A, we could use the following formula:

```
=FILTER(A:B, C:C="A")
```

| Person | Competance |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 4 |
| Name1 | 1 |
| Name1 | 2 |
| Name2 | 3 |
| Name2 | 5 |

However, I would like to make a list that gives a subtotal of these competence values. So the table should look like this:

| Person | Competance Sum |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 7 |
| Name2 | 8 |

Can I do this with 1 filter formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,FILTER(A2:B9,C2:C9="A"),
     b,TAKE(a,,1),
     c,DROP(a,,1),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(b,MMULT(N(b=TOROW(b)),c))))
```

---

Or, may be in this way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A9,C2:C9="A")),
     HSTACK(a,SUMIFS(B2:B9,A2:A9,a,C2:C9,"A")))
```

---

Comment: Genius, you are a master in Excel! The first formula worked flawlessly. Didn't try the second one.

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. Cheers mate @Jos =)